# Visual Studio SQL files not visible in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I added some .sql files to a project in my VS 2013 solution. I can see that the files have been added in Source Control Explorer, but in Solution Explorer the files don't show up in the SQL folders I added. If I click on the "Show All Files" I see an outline of the files, but I don't see why I should have to do that. In a different project of the solution these .SQL files do show up. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: The files haven't been added to the project. Right click the folder and select the "Add existing files..." option and add them. You added them to source control, but not the project.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get files added from outside the Solution to show up you need to:

- enable ' show all files' in the solution explorer
- right click on the files an select "add to solution"

This will work even if files have not yet been added to version control. They will be opened added if that is the case.